# PowerShell group DateTime in 1h steps

Tags: powershell

I want to export IIS stats with powershell, but I have only a resolution of 1d. How can I group `$log` in 1h parts?

```
foreach ($item in ($log | Group-Object -Property Date ))
{
    Write-Host $("{0};" -f $item.Name) -NoNewline
    Write-Host $("{0};" -f $(($item.Group | measure ).Count)) -NoNewline
    Write-Host $("{0:N2};" -f $(($item.Group | measure -Property Sent -Sum).Sum / 1MB)) -NoNewline
    Write-Host $("{0:N2};" -f $(($item.Group | measure -Property Received -Sum).Sum / 1MB))
}
```

**Edit:** 
Sadly this is very slow if I add `,*` to get the whole object

```
$group = $log | 
    Select-Object @{Name="Hour"; Expression={"{0} {1}" -f $_.Timestamp.Date ,$_.Timestamp.Hour}},* | 
    Group-Object -Property Hour
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Select-Object` cmdlet to extract the hour part of each `Date` as a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) and group by that property instead:

```
$log | Select-Object @{Name="Hour";Expression={$_.Date.Hour}} | Group-Object Hour
```

Comment: If I have values over two days, it would group 24 and not 48 values.

Comment: Then you could change the `Expression=` to `{"$($_.Date.Day)$($_.Date.Hour)"}`

Comment: As a more general solution you could use `{$_.Date.toString("yyyyMMdd-hh")}` so the line would look like `$log| Select-Object *,@{Name="Date1";Expression={$_.Date.toString("yyyyMMdd-hh")}} |group Date1`