# Count how many entries in CSV per Date with Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, date, datetime

Using PowerShell I am trying to summarize how many entries in a CSV file occur per day based on a date/timestamp field in the file. For example, there could be 12k lines in the file and for 3/9/2023 there are 1000 entries, for 3/8/2023 there are 5000 entries, and so on. The output just needs to say the Date and how many entries occurred on that date.

The field "Start Active Time" is the timestamp that I need to use. The date value is in this format "3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM"

The source CSV file format is below:

```
Active,Alarm,Alarm ID,Appliance,Details,Duration,Start Active Time,Last Active Time,Policy,Severity,Source Country,Source,Source Host Groups,Source Host Group Path (Outside Hosts > Countries),Source Host Name,Source Username,Source Mac Address,Source Device Type,Target Country,Target,Target Host Groups,Target Host Group Path (Outside Hosts > Countries),Target Host Name,Target Username,Target Mac Address,Target Device Type
false,Worm Propagation,7206219738387749000,fcnf,"Worm originating at 10.201.3.50, directly propagated from source host using
vnc (5900/tcp).",0,"3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM","3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM",Inside Hosts,Minor,RFC 1918,10.20.10.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,raul,,,RFC 1918,10.30.20.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,
false,Worm Propagation,7206219738387749000,fcnf,"Worm originating at 10.201.3.50, directly propagated from source host using
vnc (5900/tcp).",0,"3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM","3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM",Inside Hosts,Minor,RFC 1918,10.30.10.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,,RFC 1918,10.40.80.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,
```

I've looked the code on the following pages and tried to adapt it but I don't believe it is not reading the timestamp value correctly.

[Read a CSV file, group the data by date and calculate several columns for that date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262273/read-a-csv-file-group-the-data-by-date-and-calculate-several-columns-for-that-d)

[PowerShell group DateTime in 1h steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28148894/powershell-group-datetime-in-1h-steps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grouping on date you don't actually need to parse the date/time. You can just strip everything beginning from the comma.

In the following I'm using `ConvertFrom-Csv` only for demonstration purposes. You can replace it by `$csv = Import-Csv -Path YourFile.csv`.

```bash
$csv = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Active,Alarm,Alarm ID,Appliance,Details,Duration,Start Active Time,Last Active Time,Policy,Severity,Source Country,Source,Source Host Groups,Source Host Group Path (Outside Hosts > Countries),Source Host Name,Source Username,Source Mac Address,Source Device Type,Target Country,Target,Target Host Groups,Target Host Group Path (Outside Hosts > Countries),Target Host Name,Target Username,Target Mac Address,Target Device Type
false,Worm Propagation,7206219738387749000,fcnf,"Worm originating at 10.201.3.50, directly propagated from source host using
vnc (5900/tcp).",0,"3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM","3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM",Inside Hosts,Minor,RFC 1918,10.20.10.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,raul,,,RFC 1918,10.30.20.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,
false,Worm Propagation,7206219738387749000,fcnf,"Worm originating at 10.201.3.50, directly propagated from source host using
vnc (5900/tcp).",0,"3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM","3/3/2023, 2:33:00 AM",Inside Hosts,Minor,RFC 1918,10.30.10.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,,RFC 1918,10.40.80.254,Catch All,Inside Hosts,,,,
'@

$csv | Group-Object { $_.'Start Active Time' -replace ',.*' } -NoElement |
       Select-Object @{ n='Date'; e='Name' }, Count
```

**Output:**

```
Date     Count
----     -----
3/3/2023     2
```

**Remarks:**

- We are passing a [delay-bind script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2#using-delay-bind-script-blocks-with-parameters) to `Group-Object` to be able to group on only part of a property.
- The `-replace` operator takes a regular expression for the RHS operand. The pattern specifies "everything from the comma to the end of the string", which will be removed because we don't supply a replacement value. See [RegEx101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/IYRWPa/1).
- The `-noelement` argument makes sure `Group-Object` only outputs the `Count` and the `Name` property, without all the other CSV columns.
- Using `Select-Object` we specify a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) for `Date`, which just renames the `Name` property which is the output of `Group-Object`. We also copy the `Count` property.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I needed. I read in the file instead of pasting all the csv text in the PowerShell script. All is good now!

$csv = Import-Csv -Path

Comment: @TrashPanda Yeah, `ConvertFrom-Csv` was just used for demonstration purposes. I've added a note about using `Import-Csv` instead. Thanks!

Comment: When I run this against the whole raw CSV file it seems like the count is way higher than it should. For instance, There are approximately 3000 entries on a given day and the script says there are 8000.

Comment: @TrashPanda Are the dates always formatted in the same way? Otherwise you need to normalize them to the same format first.